# Does Bootstrap 3 have a pre-built steps option for forms?

Tags: jquery-ui, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

Couldn't find anything in the doc's but perhaps someone knows better or can suggest a work around using available properties to hack it together?

If not in bootstrap does anyone know of a gem (rails) or generator that can create the CSS/jQuery/JS?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a wizard to integrate with Bootstrap. One I know of is [this](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/#examples) but I'm sure you could find plenty more with a quick Google search.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also try this Bootstrap 3 Nav Wizard version on GitHub, LESS file is included:

**https://github.com/acornejo/bootstrap-nav-wizard**

demo here: http://acornejo.github.io/bootstrap-nav-wizard/

Preview (orig):

[image: Bootstrap 3 Nav Wizard preview 1]

Preview (customized):

[image: Bootstrap 3 Nav Wizard preview 2]

Comment: Can you tell me how you removed the white separator lines? Or, to be more specific, how do I make them thinner?

Comment: @DainisAbols: remove margin on ".nav-wizard > li:not(:last-child) > a"

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you are looking for this. Check the demo below. Just resize the window if it doesn't look like the image below.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7J94/297/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<h3>Wizard</h3>
<div class="wizard">
    <a><span class="badge">1</span> Set Global Properties</a>
    <a><span class="badge">2</span> Specify Entry Scheme</a>
    <a class="current"><span class="badge badge-inverse">3</span> Create Test Entry</a>
    <a><span class="badge">4</span> Check Your Data and Generate Portal</a>
</div>
```

**CSS** **[(or SCSS instead)](http://jsfiddle.net/H7J94/725/)**

```
.wizard a {
    padding: 10px 12px 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: #efefef;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.wizard a:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px inset transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px inset transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.wizard a:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px inset transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px inset transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #efefef;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.wizard a:first-child:before,
.wizard a:last-child:after {
    border: none;
}
.wizard a:first-child {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
            border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
.wizard a:last-child {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
       -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
            border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
.wizard .badge {
    margin: 0 5px 0 18px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}
.wizard a:first-child .badge {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.wizard .current {
    background: #007ACC;
    color: #fff;
}
.wizard .current:after {
    border-left-color: #007ACC;
}
```